# Add a custom dropdown list in Sitecore PageEditor

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

How can a custom dropdown list be added to the page editor in Sitecore?

I understand that you can create individual buttons in the toolbar by creating items under `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons` in the core DB using the `WebEdit Button` template and I understand that setting a button's `Type` field to `Common` will make it appear under the 'More' dropdown, but what I want is to create my own dropdown button with a unique list of buttons (corresponding to items in the master DB).

[image]

I've looked at the various processors in the `<getChromeData>` pipeline using dotPeek and suspect I will have to create a new processor in this pipeline, but I cannot find the relevant code which produces the 'More' dropdown list from the image.

Answer (score 2):

Create a button of template type `/sitecore/templates/System/WebEdit/WebEdit Button` and set `Type` field to `Common` from the droplist. The button should then appear in the dropdown.

[image: Type field]

[image: Custom Experience Buttons]

Comment: What I'm aiming to do is create a new button with it's own dropdown, rather than adding to the 'More' dropdown - I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Ah ok. I mis-read it. The sections are hard-coded I think, created by `renderMoreSection` function in `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page Modes/ChromeControls.js` (and the _Select Parent Element_ arrow command by `renderExpandCommand` function). The `updateCommands` function in the same file is what pushes the buttons into each section.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that extra info - that should be enough to get me to where I want. Cheers!

Comment: Great. Suggest you add a new custom `Type` and then modify the JS to add into your own section by adding a new _renderX_ function and modify `updateCommands`. Probably the neatest way with as minimum invasion possible!